# ReactJS->Appending items to an array but it says undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 arrays in two different JS files and they're declared as follows:
Index.JS:

```
const [product, setProduct] = useState([]);
const [item] = useState([
  {
    name: 'Blue Dress',
    Image: '/static/media/Dress.1c414114.png',
    Price: 540,
    id: 0,
  },
  {
    name: 'Red Dress',
    image: '/static/media/Dress.1c414114.png',
    Price: 600,
    id: 1,
  },
]);
```

Second JS file:

```
const [product, setProduct] = useState([]);
```

and that is the piece of code that appends the data to them:
Index.JS:

```
const addItem = (item) => {
  setProduct([...product, item]);
  localStorage.setItem('products', JSON.stringify(product));
};
```

second JS file:

```
const getProducts = () => {
  let X = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('products'));
  setProduct([...product, X]);
  console.log(product);
};
```

The problem is that whenever I go to the second JS file in the browser it receives the localstorage items and it, hypothethically, should add them to the product list but, after a thorough investigation, I've come to the conclusion it doesn't really add anything to it. Why is that?

Comment: This post still needs more details: what's item? When do you call getProducts? What's the expected result? Can you make a minimal reproducible sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/new ?

Comment: This is a bit confusing, your naming in particular. You switch between the singular and plural of "product" at weird times. And in your `getProducts` function, in the second file, `product` doesn't  refer to anything so it's  gonna be undefined. Might need some clarity

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new reference with this line:

```
   setProduct([...product, X])
```

after that the in both contexts products will refer to different objects unless you leverage it to the common context; You will need to define `const[product, setProduct] = useState()`  in a common context and pass it down to both components to keep them refering to the same object. e.g:

```
//common context
const [product, setProduct] = useState()

const c1 = <Component1 useState={[product,setProduct]} />
const c2 = <Component2 useState={[product,setProduct]} />

...
//components

function Component1(props){
   const [product,setProduct] = props.useState;
...
}

function Component2(props){
   const [product, SetProduct] = props.useState;
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing `localStorage.setItem` just after setting state due to which the products being set is an empty array `[]`.
You have to use `useEffect` and inside it you can set the products array.

Comment: But I'm getting the items from a button that calls the addItem function and it has an item parameter that points to the object that I want to put into the localstorage. Is there a way to do that with UseEffect? I'm new to ReactJS